# How do I attach floating vertices to the mesh?

Tags: knife-tool

I am trying to make a turbine with cuts in the sides. I did this with the knife tool and copied the vertices made with the knife tool to the areas marked on the picture. At the place where I used the knife tool I could remove the faces and create the cut shown on the picture. However, the vertices I copied are just floating in space and are not connected to the mesh. This is why the edges (see 'to here') look like they are attached but they are not. Because of this, I cannot remove the faces as I did with the original cut.

The selected area is only 1 face, I want to select the triangle in the selected area

How do I fix this? Can I attach them to the mesh? Or is there another workflow that works better?

[image: Selected area is only 1 face, I want to select the triangle in the selected area]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To join the floating vertices to the rest of the mesh, you would need to delete the faces sitting in the area, select adjacent vertices then press <kbd>F</kbd>. This will fill in edges between the vertices, and once you've gotten all the lines, you can fill in the faces by selecting edges and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image: Image filling in]

There are a couple of ways you could have gone about doing this differently though. The first way would be using the *Cut Through* option for the knife tool. You'd use it by first pressing <kbd>3</kbd> on the Numpad to enter the side orthographic view, pressing <kbd>K</kbd> to enable the knife tool, than <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle cutting through. What this will do is create the cuts on all parts of the meshes that your cutting lines project onto, including the far side of the turbine.

[image: Cut through]

A better way to have gone about modelling it would be deleting half of the turbine and applying a *Mirror* modifier to reflect the object across its origin, thereby cutting the modelling time in half.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your thorough explanation! If I would use the mirror modifier, could I also keep a quarter of the turbine that has the cut and mirror the other 3 quarters around the symmetry axis/origin, so that every quarter has a cut?

Comment: Yes, that could work too, though the quarter turbine would have a half-cut on each end. Another thing to note is that if you have any details that shouldn't be mirrored across all four quarters, you'll have to apply the modifier before you can add those details.